# Can I make a filter initialize after the servlet?

Tags: servlet-filters

I have a web application using spring, in which I have a servlet that locads the context in its init method:

```
private ContextLoader contextLoader;

public void init() throws ServletException {
    contextLoader = new ContextLoader();
    contextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());   
}
```

In addition, I have a servlet in which I do the following:

```
public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    WebApplicationContext context =
       WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(config.getServletContext());
    //here I'm using the context
}
```

The problem: the filter's init() method is called before the servlet initializes, so the context I get in the filter is null. In the web.xml my servlet is configured with load-on-startup=1.

Is there any way I can make my filter initialize after the servlet initializes so that I'll be able to use the WebApplicationContext in the filter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Don't configure the filter in the web.xml
2. In your servlet, get the ServletContext.
3. Call ServletContext.addFilter() to add your filter.